# What does "set to root of installation" mean?

Tags: linux, github, installation, environment-variables, root

I'm still new to these kinds of computer terminologies. Can you help clarify something for me.

If I'm installing a piece of software from github and it says "set the environment variable... to the root of the installation"
Does that just mean that I should set the environment variable to the folder where I downloaded the software from?

ex:  If I install something to /home/user/workspace
Would I then just set the environment variable to " = /home/user/workspace "

Please and Thank you.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Yes. Here "root" means the top level directory, under which the other directories and files of the installed package will be placed.

Comment: thank you thank you. I'm still learning linux and the term "root" always seemed like a bigger beast than I thought it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered the question yourself! The root serves as a directory in this case

Comment: yep! I wasn't comfortable enough to trust my gut when it comes to messing with linux stuff